# An Internal Server Error Has Occurred while - Upload "Managed -Released" package Twice

Tags: managed-package, upload, release

I was having one Managed-Release Package uploaded and installed it in Demo Org, While Testing I Found that still there is a bug which I missed while testing with "Managed-Beta" uploaded package.

Now I have done few Changes with Managed-Release package which was previously uploaded once, Now I am trying to upload it again its giving me some sort of error message **"An internal server error has occurred"** with ERROR ID.

Do It will work - What I am trying ? and Do all changes will reflect in the same like Managed-Beta do ?

Comment: Sometimes, for some reason, you can delete (or rename) classes or delete fields that were already managed released. If you have done that, that could lead to this error.

Comment: Check, if all classes and triggers compile and all VF pages are valid. Otherwise you would get Internal Server Error messages on package upload.

Comment: The packaging process compiles all the classes and runs the tests. This is an error where the upgrade process is hitting an unexpected condition. Personally I've seen problems when the signature of an inner Apex class is changed from version to version of a managed package and the installation process has used the old version of the inner class with a new version of the containing class. Passing the internal server error numbers to support may allow them to suggest the problem area and so allow you to wind back the problem change in the next managed package version.

Comment: Do you have any permission sets referencing standard objects? I have seen internal errors when a permission set references a standard object that is master, custom that is in your package

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with my two different apps, where I was having "StandardController" used which I have removed later in my current package, this is the only change I have done there. Any Solutions or suggestion into what should I look??

Comment: @NileshMendhe Did the provided answer work? If so, please accept.

Answer (score 3):

This error pops up when one of your Apex classes has somehow become 'invalid' and no longer compiles. It might be certain references that are no longer valid, or a test class that was not updated with the updated Apex class.

Anyhow, to fix it, go to `Setup -> Develop -> Apex classes` and click `compile all`. If you're lucky, it will give some comprehensible information about what's going on. If it doesn't work as you want, open up all your Apex Classes, and save them again one by one. You'll hit an error somewhere. Fix those, and the upload should go smoothly afterwards.

To speed up this process, you could check the "isvalid" flag on the metadata of your apex classes to find out which class is not valid.